# Explanation on how does the memcpy function behaves?

Tags: c, memcpy, string.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char lists[10][25];
char name[10];

void main()
{
    scanf("%s" , lists[0]);
    memcpy(name , lists[0], 25);

    printf("%s\n" , name);
}
```

In the above code I am predefining the size of character array "name" as 10.
Now when I gave the input as :

Input - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy

The output I got was the same string : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy

Should'nt I get the output as : abcdefghij ???

how this is becoming possible even though the size of array is limited to 10?

Comment: This is an example of *undefined behavior* which means anything may happen. Including the program working as it should.

Comment: Your code is coloring outside of the lines, very basic UB.  If you want it to blow up and reformat the disk then you need more colors.  Swapping the two variable declarations is worth a try.

Comment: Most languages prevent you, the programmer, from writing past the end of an array. C does not. It's your responsibility to guard against this.

Comment: You might get segmentation fault in memcpy since your copy is going out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't know the size of the allocated memory it's writing into, and you got away with where the extra data got written. You might not on another platform, or using a different compiler, or different optimisation settings.

When passing the `size` parameter to `memcpy ()`, it's a good idea to take the size of the destination memory into account.

When using char arrays, if you want to be safer about not overrunning memory, you can use `strncpy ()`. It'll take care of inserting the trailing `NULL` in the right place.

Comment: So you mean to say that if the block of memory available to me was 10 then this would'nt have happened ?

Comment: No, if the memory were 25 then you'd have no problems. C does depend on the programmer being careful about memory allocations and writing, etc

Comment: I meant to say that the available physical memory was only 10 then I would not be able to find some extra memory and then it would have raised an error or something ! Right ??

Comment: Yes you might get segmentation fault if you are copying out of bounds

Comment: No, again, because `memcpy` has no knowledge about where it's copying and can't protect you. If you only have 10 bytes, pass 10 in as the size and it will make sure it only copies 10 bytes. But then your string won't be correctly NULL-terminated, so you'll have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, arrays are pointers. In C there are no length checks like on Java for example.

When you write `char a[2];` the OS gives you space on the memory for 2 chars.
For example, let the memory be

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|
 a
```

`a` is a pointer to the address 1. The `a[0] = 0;` is equal with `*(a+0) = 0`, meaning `write 0 to the address a + offset 0`.

So if you try to write to an address that you have not allocated, unexpected things can happen.

For example, lets say we have `char a[2];char b[2];` and the memory map is

```
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|
 a   b
```

Then the `a[2] = 0` is equal to `b[0] = 0`. But if this address is an address of an other program, then a segmentation error will be raised.

Try the program (it may work with no optimizations of the compiler):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char a[4];
char b[4];

void main()
{
    scanf("%s" , a);    // input "12345678"
    printf("%s\n" , b); // print     "5678"
}
```

`memcpy` just copies from an address to the other the size of data you said.

In your example, you were luky because all the addresses you accessed where assigned to your program (inside your's memory page).

In C/C++ you are responsible to handle the memory correctly. Also, keep in mind that strings end at the char `\0` so inside an array `char str[10];` we usually have tops 9 chars and the `\0`.

Comment: I think you have a typo here: "The a[0] = 0; is equal with *(a+1) = 0, meaning write 0 to the address a + offset 0."

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you. (It's now correct)

Comment: "|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12| a b Then the a[2] = 0 is equal to b[0] = 0." If you're relying on this behavior you're in for a world of hurt. There's no telling what the compiler / optimizer might do.

Comment: In the first example, this is the hypothesis. On the code, hopefully the compiler will assign the variables sequentially. In any way as I mentioned "if you try to write to an address that you have not allocated, unexpected things can happen", `a[2]` is such an address.

Comment: Got it. I first thought you were implying the allocation would *necessarily* be laid out in that sequential manner. I see you are saying *assuming the variables are* laid out in this manner .... then the behavior would be as follows ....